# Apache Flink : Extract TypeInformation of Tuple

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using FlinkKafkaConsumer09 wherein I have a ByteArrayDeseializationSchema implementing KeyedDeserializationSchema> , now in the getProducedType how do I extract the TypeInformation.

I read in the documentation that TypeExtractor.getForClass method does not support ParameterizedTypes , which method of TypeExtractor should I use to to achieve this ?

I think we have to use createTypeInfo method , can you please tell me how do I use this to return the TypeInformation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the returned type of your deserialization schema is a `byte[]` then you can use `PrimitiveArrayTypeInfo.BYTE_PRIMITIVE_ARRAY_TYPE_INFO` as the return value of `getProducedType`.

Comment: thank you for answering , below line worked for me
    `TypeInformation<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>> typeInformation =     TypeInformation
       .of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>>() {
       });`
This is what I need
    `public TypeInformation<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>> getProducedType() {
  return typeInformation;
 }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `TypeInformation` of `Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>` :

```
return TupleTypeInfo.getBasicAndBasicValueTupleTypeInfo(byte[].class, byte[].class)
```

could be possible ?

Comment: Thomas, this does not work .. I have solved this issue :
`return TypeInfoParser.parse("Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>");`

Comment: To extract type info from tuple :
`TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple3<Integer, Long, byte[]>>() {
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Type Hints in the Java API

To help cases where Flink cannot reconstruct the erased generic type information, the Java API offers so called type hints from version 0.9 on. The type hints tell the system the type of the data set produced by a function. The following gives an example:

```
DataSet<SomeType> result = dataSet
    .map(new MyGenericNonInferrableFunction<Long, SomeType>())
        .returns(SomeType.class);
```

The returns statement specifies the produced type, in this case via a class. The hints support type definition through

```
Classes, for non-parameterized types (no generics)
Strings in the form of returns("Tuple2<Integer, my.SomeType>"), which are parsed and converted to a TypeInformation.
A TypeInformation directly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
case class CaseClassForYourExpectedMessage(key:String,value:String)

/* getProducedType method */
override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[CaseClassForYourExpectedMessage] =
TypeExtractor.getForClass(classOf[CaseClassForYourExpectedMessage])
```